# WebStorm git difftool -d closes immediately without waiting for user

Tags: windows, git, webstorm, git-difftool

Running `git difftool -d <commit> <commit>` on Windows opens the WebStorm diff tool but the contents disappear as soon as it starts.

Tried trustExitCode, prompt and the [bat file](https://gist.github.com/rambabusaravanan/1d1902e599c9c680319678b0f7650898).

```
[diff]
        tool = webstorm
[difftool "webstorm"]
        cmd = \"C:/Users/<me>/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/WebStorm 2018.1.2/bin/webstorm64.exe\" diff \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because JetBrains WebStorm is already open so the diff is passed off to the existing instance and the diff command returns. As soon as it returns, git does a cleanup and poof the contents are gone.

Solutions:

1. Close WebStorm before diff. Only useful if not using WebStorm for editing.
2. Hold the shell with sleep or `cmd //c "pause"`. After closing the diff window, return to shell and press Ctrl+c. Or start the difftool as `git difftool -d <commit> <commit> &`.

   - `cmd = \"C:/Users/<me>/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/WebStorm 2018.1.2/bin/webstorm64.exe\" diff \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" && sleep 3600`

Similar issue on Mac: [Using IntelliJ as git mergetool always exits as soon as soon as it starts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25636912/using-intellij-as-git-mergetool-always-exits-as-soon-as-soon-as-it-starts)