# BeyondCompare git difftool -d closes immediately without waiting for user

Tags: git, diff, beyondcompare

Note: this is similar to [WebStorm git difftool -d closes immediately without waiting for user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54317405/webstorm-git-difftool-d-closes-immediately-without-waiting-for-user), but for Beyond Compare

When I run `git difftool -d` with Beyond Compare set as my default difftool, git closes right away without letting Beyond Compare show any comparisons. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 3):

Much like similar issues, I had Beyond Compare open and it likes to run as a single instance. Though, that wasn't my entire problem. My diff tool was referencing the wrong executable. `BCompare.exe` is the primary executable that will be a single instance if it can. `BComp.exe` is the executable you should be using for the merge tool.

Why? It is actually kind of cool I think. The second one opens the first if an instance isn't open (obviously). The interesting part here is that the second waits for the associated documents/tasks to be closed in the main program before returning a value. This means that you can open additional files in a Beyond Compare instance opened by git and git will still get a return code for the initial file when you close that file. I am tempted to do some fancy drawing to illustrate, but I currently don't the time or skills to do that.

If that doesn't solve your issue, you can tack on `-solo` to the command. It will open another UI instance in that case though.

Answer (score 0):

There are chances, that your version of Beyond Compare does not work as expected.  See discussion [Scooter's forum](https://forum.scootersoftware.com/forum/beyond-compare-3-discussion/folder-compare/3697-does-bcomp-wait-for-folder-compares-to-end?p=32434#post32434).  Check at commandline prompt if

1. `bcomp file1 file2` waits until closing the window.
2. `bcomp dir1 dir2` waits until closing the window.
3. `bcompare -solo dir1 dir2` waits until closing the window.

(1) probably works.

(2) Is not expected to wait, according to the forum.

(3) I found that this does not work either, although it should, according to [command line reference](https://www.scootersoftware.com/v4help/index.html?command_line_reference.html).

If even (3) does not help, you can edit `mergetools/bc` file.  Add this line to the end of `diff_cmd()`:

```
[ -d "$LOCAL" -o -d "$REMOTE" ] && [ -t 0 ] && read -p "Press ENTER to continue..."
```

Location of the file is `/lib/git-core/mergetools/bc` or something similar.  In my gitforwindows, it is `c:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\mergetools\bc`.